# mod_security: track user to check if redirected to login failed page

Tags: mod-security

I have to log when a user fails to log in to a web application. Unfortunately, this web application is not able to do this out of the box and I can not change it.

Now I'm experimenting with mod_security. My idea is to track the POST request, extract the username and then check if the user gets redirected to the "login failed" page.

I have:

```
<Location /login.php>
       # Sanitize password variable value
       SecAction nolog,phase:2,sanitiseArg:password

       SecRule REQUEST_BODY "username=(.*)&password" "capture,log,logdata:'login submitted: user %{TX.1}'"
</Location>
```

and

```
<Location /loginfailed.php>
       # Filter und log redirects to loginfailed
       SecRule RESPONSE_BODY "loginfailed.php" "phase:4,t:none,log,logdata:'login failed: %{TX.1}'"
</Location>
```

But of course "TX.1" is already unset when I need it the second time.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unless the web app includes information about the username in the redirect (say, in the query string `/loginfiled.php?username=foobar` or in a cookie) there will be no way to extract the username from the `/loginfailed.php` request.  The information just isn't there to extract.  HTTP is stateless, so when a client sends `username=foo` in the body of a POST request and this results in a 302 redirect, the follow up request to `/loginfailed.php` doesn't know anything about the previous request.

If this web app uses a 307 redirect instead of a 302 or a 303, the follow up request to `/loginfailed.php` will be a POST request with all the same data.  I would expect this to be fairly unlikely.

Have a look in the cookies or the session storage and see if the username is there.  (I'm not sure if `mod_security` can read session storage but if you know it's there, I'm sure you can figure something out.)

You might have more luck with a `CustomLog` to log whether the login attempt succeeded or failed during the original request rather than the follow up request:

```
LogFormat "%h %t \"%r\" %>s %{Location}o %{PHPSESSID}C %{UNIQUE_ID}e" loginslog
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/logins.log" loginslog
```

or you could just add the `Location:` header and the unique ID to your normal logs with `%{Location}o %{UNIQUE_ID}e`.  `mod_security` includes the unique ID in all of its logs so you can match on to the other easily.

Creating a coherent log of all usernames that have failed logins is then a matter of grepping all the `Location:.*/loginfailed.php` lines out of the `logins.log` and then matching the unique IDs up to the usernames in your existing mod_security-based log.